# After success payment from paypal, I need transaction id to store in my db

Tags: methods, paypal, return

I have setup everything on PayPal and it works well.
My main concern is, when payment is done, I have setup for redirect to my website, 
so when payment is done, it goes to my website by Paypal in GET method, I need this in post method, so I have used hidden type rm=2, but still I am not getting desired method.

Answer (score 1):

As per you question in the header, if you would like to store the transaction id in your database, you could make use of IPN or PDT. Which helps in maintaining your inventory management. 'txn_id' is the variable. check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) for the available variables.
If you enable Auto Return, the values are always going to get returned only in GET even if rm is set to 2.